# Styles working in emulator but not In actual device

Tags: android, android-theme

I need a activity that is transparent,
So I used this styles to make it possible.
It's properly working in emulator but not in Android Device.

[This is working in emulator but not in actual device.

I Always received App is not working..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUPmE.png)

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

 <style name="Transparent" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPopup</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: add your screen to understand more

Comment: I added a screenshot.

Comment: what is Android version on your device?

Comment: 5.0 is the android version of my device

Comment: I was able to solve the problem, I saw some posts here that primary color doesn't accept opaque. Thanks though..